# CSS how to transition(with transform) a parent and child both, differently

Tags: css, css-transitions

To clarify, I want to create a "hover" transition in css only, where the hover state of one DIV animates another DIV (this I can get to work using "~" selector). And then, animate(w/transition) multiple children inside of the second DIV.

It seems, that I cannot animate the child div if the parent is animated. Here's an example: a button to the left which upon hovering activates the transition/transform animation of the second div (a red half circle): (I want the two half-circles to rotate at different times (delay), and for different periods of time (duration))

http://jsfiddle.net/dXCK6/2/

```
    .mommy {
    width:300px;
    height:56px;
    background-color:hsla(40, 50%, 60%, .6);
    position:absolute;
    left:240px;
}
.daddy {
    visibility:visible;
    width:170px;
    height:170px;
    border-radius:50%;
    background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, hsla(10, 90%, 50%, 1) 50%, hsla(100, 90%, 50%, .0) 50%);
    position:absolute;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    -webkit-transition:0s;
    transition:0s;
}
.mommy:hover ~ .daddy {
    visibility:visible;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-transition: .6s ease-in .2s;
    transition: .6s ease-in .2s;
}
.baby {
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    border-radius:50%;
    background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, hsla(5, 35%, 50%, 1) 50%, hsla(100, 90%, 50%, .0) 50%);
    position: relative;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-transition:0s;
    transition:0s;
}
.mommy:hover ~ .baby {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-transition: .1s ease-in .9s;
    transition: .1s ease-in .9s;
}
```

Please note:
1)There must be positioning, visibility, and everything that's in that jsfiddle. 2)in the example, I have "baby" set to a different transition time but you cannot see it happen (this is my problem) 3)

Comment: **different transition time** it's just the `transition-duration:.1s` and `transition-delay:.9s` and looks like they work OK for me. What's exactly the effect you want?

Comment: what I want is for the two half-circles to rotate at different times (delay), and for different periods of time (duration). And I cannot seem to change the child's, as it sticks to the parent.

Comment: It makes more sense, I've found what's wrong but the exact effect is still unclear, see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact you have a wrong selector (which is `.mommy:hover ~ .baby`), so the animation for the `.baby` in fact does not run. Only the animation of the parent `.daddy` is run, it rotates and makes the inner child `.baby` also rotate. This effect made you think both animations run at the same time. Also because of this effect, I'm not sure what the exact effect you want. I've tried editing the code **mainly** to show that both animations can work right on the hovering:

```
/* This is what the selector should be */
.mommy:hover ~ .daddy > .baby {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  -webkit-transition: .1s ease-in .9s;
  transition: .1s ease-in .9s;
}
```

### [Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/dXCK6/4/)

Comment: Thanks! I am learning css as I go, and selectors are still confusing. your solution does seem to work, but here http://jsfiddle.net/dXCK6/5/ where I set the deg back to 0, it doesn't seem to animate. What I want is for the two halfcircles to animate the same, but one right after the other, and slower or faster.

Comment: @PLCcory your initial transform is `0deg`, hovering makes it `0deg` so how can it animate? Note that there should be some difference between the start and end values to trigger the transition.

Comment: Yup, I made a mistake.  Thanks for your help and teaching me a new selector.

Comment: @PLCcory I think I know the effect you want but as I said in the answer, rotating the parent **also rotates** the inner child. That's why it's very hard to get the effect you want (with the current HTML), your `.daddy` and `.baby` should be rotated **independently** but now rotating the `.daddy` also rotates the `.baby`. If possible, you can place the `.baby` out of the `.daddy` and position it correctly. It's not really good but it's much easier to get the effect you want.